# Does mio::poll produce a true memory leak and can I ignore it?

Tags: rust, valgrind

I want to poll a character device to check for an interrupt. My code appears to work but I'm getting a memory leak when I run my code under Valgrind.

I have reduced the code to a minimum example which still produces the memory leak:

```rust
use mio::Poll;

fn main() {
    // Construct a new `Poll` handle
    let _poll = Poll::new().unwrap();
}
```

I expect `_poll` to be dropped cleanly when it goes out of scope. However, when run under Valgrind, the above code produces the following output:

```
==4771== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4771== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4771== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4771== Command: ./target/debug/poll_test
==4771== 
==4771== Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==4771==    at 0x49B2BAC: epoll_ctl (syscall-template.S:78)
==4771==    by 0x10DDC7: mio::sys::unix::epoll::Selector::register (epoll.rs:98)
==4771==    by 0x10FA0B: <mio::sys::unix::eventedfd::EventedFd<'a> as mio::event_imp::Evented>::register (eventedfd.rs:97)
==4771==    by 0x10FDFB: <mio::sys::unix::io::Io as mio::event_imp::Evented>::register (io.rs:65)
==4771==    by 0x10E97F: <mio::sys::unix::awakener::pipe::Awakener as mio::event_imp::Evented>::register (awakener.rs:63)
==4771==    by 0x10AB7F: mio::poll::Poll::new (poll.rs:665)
==4771==    by 0x10A797: poll_test::main (main.rs:5)
==4771==    by 0x10A62B: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}} (rt.rs:64)
==4771==    by 0x1190AF: {{closure}} (rt.rs:49)
==4771==    by 0x1190AF: std::panicking::try::do_call (panicking.rs:297)
==4771==    by 0x11B407: __rust_maybe_catch_panic (lib.rs:87)
==4771==    by 0x119A8B: try<i32,closure> (panicking.rs:276)
==4771==    by 0x119A8B: catch_unwind<closure,i32> (panic.rs:388)
==4771==    by 0x119A8B: std::rt::lang_start_internal (rt.rs:48)
==4771==    by 0x10A5FB: std::rt::lang_start (rt.rs:64)
==4771==  Address 0xbde4b10c is on thread 1's stack
==4771==  in frame #1, created by mio::sys::unix::epoll::Selector::register (epoll.rs:91)
==4771==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4771==    at 0x10DD40: mio::sys::unix::epoll::Selector::register (epoll.rs:91)
==4771== 
==4771== 
==4771== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4771==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==4771==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 17 frees, 2,137 bytes allocated
==4771== 
==4771== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==4771==    at 0x484A004: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so)
==4771== 
==4771== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4771==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4771==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4771==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4771==    still reachable: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==4771==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4771== 
==4771== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4771== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Why does this code produce a memory leak? Can I fix it? If not, can I safely ignore it?

Comment: If you pass the suggested `--leak-check=full` to valgrind, it should print out the stack trace of the point where said memory was allocated, this would be quite helpful to know where it comes from. Also note that it is marked as "still reachable", not "lost", so it could be reclaimed.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I have re run the code and passed `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes` to valgrind. My last edit added the stack trace to the question.

Comment: Oompf. It's a bit disappointing because you get no stack trace for the leak, it just says `calloc` (which is a `malloc` returning zero-ed memory). You could try to remove `mio` from you program, compile an empty `main` with no dependencies, and see if this "leak" is still reported.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I tried running an empty `main` after removing `mio` and there were no issues (`All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible`).

Comment: Unless it's hiding in another file, it looks like `Drop` isn't implemented for `Poll` and it's creating an `Arc`: https://github.com/tokio-rs/mio/blob/master/src/poll.rs

Comment: https://github.com/tokio-rs/mio/issues/776